# execute OBIEE wlst command by java

Tags: java, obiee, wlst

i'm having a prolem about getting Role from java when using wlst.
my code following:

```
import weblogic.management.scripting.WLST;
import weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter;
public class JavaTestWLST {
    public JavaTestWLST() {

    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            WLST.ensureInterpreter();
            WLSTInterpreter interpreter = WLST.getWLSTInterpreter();                        
            interpreter.exec("connect('admin','admin','t3://server:7001')");                        
            interpreter.exec("listAppRoles('obi')");    
           //or interpreter.exec("listAppRoles(appStripe='obi')"); 
           //still eror NameError: listAppRole

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception_111:"+e.toString());          
        }   
    }   
}
```

I've connected sussessfully but having a error.
Error:
Exception:Traceback (innermost last):
File "", line 1, in ?
NameError: listAppRoles

Please help me
Thanks.

Comment: Thank for your answer, after replacing by interpreter.exec("listAppRoles( appStripe='obi')"); i still having the same error as befor. i don't known why? Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function module which you are calling this is going to takes the HashMap object (key,value pair). The arugument must be passed with key. Like this listAppRoles(appStripe="appName")
Your code line could be change accordingly as shown below:

```
interpreter.exec("listAppRoles( appStripe='obi')");
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, after replacing by interpreter.exec("listAppRoles( appStripe='obi')"); i still having the same error as befor. i don't known why? Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic has two paths to run wlst from.

/$ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin
/$ORACLE_HOME/wlserver_10.3/common/bin

If you run wlst.sh from /oracle_common/common/bin it will work successfully.

Steps:
cd /$ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin
./wlst.sh

wls:/offline> connect ('weblogic', 'welcome1', 'localhost:7001')
wls:/bifoundation_domain/serverConfig> listAppRoles(appStripe="obi")

Regards